# How to drop a database if a variable with its logical name exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I created a variable containing the logical name of a database, and drop it if this is present in my `LocalDB`.

The problem that I am facing in my current code is that it only searches in the physical names of the existing databases.

(I have a database with the logical name 'Development' which does not get removed).

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
SET @dbname = 'Development'

IF(EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM sys.databases 
          WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname OR name = @dbname )))   
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';'
    FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
    WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@dbname) AND SPId <> @@SPId

    EXEC(@sql)

    EXEC('DROP DATABASE ' + @dbname);

    PRINT 'Existing database removed'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Database not present';
END
```

The result I get is the print 'Database not present' and the db is not removed. 
What I would like is a deleted database (`.mdf` and `.ldf`)

Comment: Database name in the `sys.databases` table isn't quoted. So, a database (foolishly) called `My silly [database] name` would have a value of `My silly [database] name` for `name`, not `'[My silly [database]] name]'`. Also, I would suggest you *do* quote `EXEC('DROP DATABASE ' + @dbname);` (`EXEC('DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname));`

Comment: What do you mean "logical database name"? I've never heard of this and don't see any promising search results

Comment: database is offline at the time of delete/drop? did you rename database? IF YES, you have to mention physical database name (name which using in server)

Comment: @MartinSmith with "logical database name" I refer to the name the database has on the server, this is a simple short word. The alternative is the physical name, which is the full path to the .mdf file.

Comment: @CR241 The database is not offline at the time of drop. I also did not rename the database. However I am not the creator of the database, so the physical name is different than where the creator stored it. Thanks I will give the physical name a go.

Comment: so that is the logical file name, not the database name. you would need to look in `sys.sysaltfiles` or similar to get the database id corresponding to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *database* doesn't have the logical name "development". One of the files it contains has that logical name.

To get the database name corresponding to the logical file name you can use

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id)
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE name = 'Development'
```

And then assign that to `@dbname` - there may be multiple results. There is no guarantee that logical file name is unique across databases

Answer (score 1):

The user executing the query probably does not have permissions to see the database.

> If the caller of sys.databases is not the owner of the database and
>   the database is not master or tempdb, the minimum permissions required
>   to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or the VIEW ANY
>   DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the
>   master database. The database to which the caller is connected can
>   always be viewed in sys.databases.

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Try running the below query in SSMS to check if you can see your database.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```